# How to edit model on show view of other model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the model `Customer`, and binded by `has_many` model `Location`. This is customer and his locations (adresses). After creating a new customer application redirects on `show` view of `Customer` model (shows all data just entered). On `show` view I have form for location add. There are already entered locations shows on this view and each of them has the link to edit each separate location. I need, when user click on location edit link, he redirects to `show` view of `Customer` model, but the form already contains the data of clicked location. `Show` view code of `Customer` model:

```
<p>Customer info:<br>
<strong><%= @customer.name %></strong><br />
<%= @customer.kind.name %><br />
<%= @customer.adres %><br />
<%= @customer.phone %><br />
<%= @customer.comment %><br />
</p>
<h3>Delivery location:</h3>

<% if @locations %>
<ul>
<% @locations.each do |loc| %>
  <li>
    <%= loc.adres %>
    <%= loc.phone %>
    <%= loc.comment %>
  </li>
<% end %>
</ul>
<% end %>

<%= form_for Location.new do |l| %>
  <%= l.text_field :adres %><br>
  <%= l.text_field :phone %><br>
  <%= l.text_field :comment %><br>
  <%= l.text_field :customer_id, type: "hidden", value: @customer.id %><br>
  <%= l.submit "Add" %>
<% end %>

<%= link_to "Home", root_path %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd just set `@location` depending on whether specific params have been sent:

```
#app/controllers/customers_controller.rb
class CustomersController < ApplicationController
   def show
      @customer = Customer.find params[:id]
      @location = params[:location_id] ? @customer.locations.find(params[:location_id]) : @customer.locations.new 
   end
end
```

This would allow you to populate the form as follows:

```
#app/views/customers/show.html.erb
Customer info:<br>
<%= content_tag :strong, @customer.name %>
<%= @customer.kind.name %>
<%= @customer.adres %>
<%= @customer.phone %>
<%= @customer.comment %>

<h3>Delivery location:</h3>
<% if @customer.locations %>
  <ul>
    <% @customer.locations.each do |loc| %>
      <%= content_tag :li do %>
        <%= loc.adres %>
        <%= loc.phone %>
        <%= loc.comment %>
        <%= link_to "Edit", customer_path(@customer, location_id: loc.id) %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>

<%= form_for @location do |l| %>
  <%= l.text_field :adres %><br>
  <%= l.text_field :phone %><br>
  <%= l.text_field :comment %><br>
  <%= l.text_field :customer_id, type: "hidden", value: @customer.id %><br>
  <%= l.submit %>
<% end %>
```

--

To manage the `routes` (to pass `location_id`), you'll be best creating a custom route:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :customers do
   get ":location_id", on: :member, action: :show, as: :location #-> url.com/customers/:id/:location_id
end
```

This will mean you'll have to reference the other link in your view:

```
<%= link_to "Edit", customer_location_path(@customer, loc.id) %>
```

Comment: thank you for help! It works, but I have one problem. If there is no parameter location_id for customer_path, i have locations collections increased by 1 element (i think, its a new location element without any attributes). So, my location list has 1 extra line with no data

Comment: I think, I should check for one necessary attribute and paste <li> element, like this <% if loc.adres %>
    <li> 
It worked

Comment: Instead of `if`, use [`try`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.5/classes/Object.html#method-i-try) - `<%= loc.try(:adres) %>`